# Why isn't there an "about" link on GLU?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I'm missing a link to [about](https://german.stackexchange.com/about) on GLU and GLUmeta. On other SE sites this link is between meta/main and faq.

GLU:
 [image]

ELU:
 [image]

Comment: It's there if you log out. Some sites have the about link when logged in, some don't. Maybe it has to do with beta status or with the space all your badges need after you logged in.

Comment: @JohnSmithers Beta was also my first idea, but other betas do have that, too. Badges are also unlikely, but an idea worth ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [an answer on MSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/72044/150010): the **about** link disappears when you get the [moderator tools](https://german.stackexchange.com/privileges/moderator-tools) privilege, which you’ve got here but not yet on EL&U.